# Move modifier up/ down and to first/ last with hotkeys

Tags: modifiers, keymap

Is it possible to move a modifier up/down or to the first/ last position within the modifier stack?

[image]

If I hotkey the operators for "Move to First" and "Move to Last" from the dropdown, Blender requires a modifier name.

[image]

Also, is it possible to navigate to the previous/ next modifier in the stack using hotkeys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifiers can be moved to the first place in the stack using: "object.modifier_move_to_index", with the Index set to 0.
The last place index is dependent on the number of modifiers and since the index cannot be -1, this cannot be used for moving to the last position.

Answer (score 4):

Install the hotkeys in the `Property Editor` section without a modifier name:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just drag here: [image]

and drop where you want it to have:

[image]

you can right click here:

[image]

and then assign shortcut.

[image]

Comment: The shortcut for these operators only works if you specify the modifier name, so it does not work without. It only works if you use it from the dropdown, not with a shortcut.